# Array reading max as one more than input

Tags: arrays, c, max, scanf, mean

**Warning: I am extremely new to coding. If this code looks like a mess, it's because it is.**

I had this code literally working perfectly... until my laptop restarted randomly and I lost all my code. I had to rewrite it and now, for some reason, when I enter an array, it adds one extra number to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int length = 0;
    int arr[length];
    int i;
    
    do {
        printf("please enter a positive nonzero integer: \n");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        if (length <= 0)
        printf("Length is invalid. Try again. \n");
    }
    while (length <= 0);
    
    printf("please enter %d numbers: \n", length);
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; ++i) {
          scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        } 
        while (length <= 0);
        
    int min = arr[0];
    int max = arr[0];
    double sum = arr[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        sum = sum + arr[i];
  }
  
  printf("Minimum is: %d\n Maximum is: %d\n Mean is: %f\n", min, max, sum/length);
  return 0;
}
```

Example: array length = 5, array = 1 2 3 4 5
min= 1, max = 6, mean = 4

I'm so stuck and just defeated. I can't look at this any more.

Comment: `i <= length` should be `i < length`. With your code, if `length` is `5`, `i` will be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`, for a total of `6` literations, one more than needed.

Comment: you wrote <=length instead of <length

Comment: Put off defining the array until AFTER the user has entered the `length` they want to use...

Comment: @Fe2O3 , your solution worked, but do you know how to make this work if my array has negative decimal integers in it?

Comment: Apart from the several `<= length` (that should all be `< length`, as noted by others) there's no particular reason I can see that positive/negative should be an issue. Perhaps you're expecting the _wrong_ outcome??

Comment: @Fe2O3 Originally I had the length written as "<length" and changed it due to my desperation LOL. Also, I'm entering decimals and getting numbers in the thousands for my min and max, so idk LOL

Comment: To be a good coder, one has to _really_ read (and mentally "compile") every line of code, questioning if it makes sense. To visit every element of C's "zero indexed" arrays, the boundary is always `<`; never `<=`... Now, look at your code again... What is the purpose of the 2nd `do/while()` loop? You have to train yourself to think like a coder...

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C are indexed starting from `0`. An array with a length of `5` has indexes at `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. By checking that your index is less than *or equal* to the length, you're indexing out of bounds. This results in undefined behavior.

As an example, your `for` loop should be the following, subbing `<=` for `<` and starting at `0`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    }

    if (arr[i] < min) {
        min = arr[i];
    }

    sum = sum + arr[i];
}
```